# Visual Studio 2013 - Change background color of Peek Definition Window

Tags: background, color-scheme, visual-studio-2013

I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, Resharper 8 and own color scheme from http://studiostyl.es/.

I would like change background color in peek definition window because now is yellow :(.

Maybe this cause own color scheme. I am not sure. It is possible change background color of peek window in Visual Studio?

Now look like this :(

[image: http://s24.postimg.org/qudxqbrut/peek_definiton_window.jpg]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way I resolved this was through the following steps:

1. Navigate to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
2. Make sure Text Editor is selected within the "Show settings for:" drop down
3. Within the "Display items:" list box find all Peek settings and adjust to your preferred styling.

Hope this helps.

[image: Peek Definition settings]

Comment: In German it's "Hintergrund für das Definitionsfenster" and "Hintergrund ohne Fokus als Vorschau anzeigen". Just to help anyone who comes along, I looked for that for a while... :)