# Changing color of peek window in visual studio 2017 does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The problem is that :
Theme of my vs is Light but Peek window is like this : 
[image]

It shows with strange color ! I searched a lot about this strange problem but I did not find any correct solution. Also I checked [Visual Studio 2013 - Change background color of Peek Definition Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572332/visual-studio-2013-change-background-color-of-peek-definition-window). It does not help me and I think my problem is relate to version of Visual Studio (2017).

point is that If I change them to Dark, it is working fine.

Also I changed Peek color from (Tools -> Option -> Font end Color -> Peek background color) but it does not change anything. Restared VS many times and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem is related to one of Colorized extension on my Visual Studio.
I removed it and it is working fine now.